# MonetDB Prepare Statement in Function

Tags: sql, monetdb

I'm trying to create a function that takes the parameters for the column, the table, the limit, and offset. Basically, I want to be able to get a specified number of rows data from a specified table from a specified column.

However, I'm unable to get the following code to work - I get several errors such as:

```
syntax error, unexpected SELECT, expecting ':' in: "create function get_banana(lim int, off int, tbl varchar(32), col varchar(32)) r"
syntax error, unexpected RETURN in: "return"
syntax error, unexpected END in: "end"
```

These errors seem kind of meaningless.

My code is as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GET_BANANA(lim int, off int, tbl varchar(32), col varchar(32)) 
RETURNS TABLE (clm int) 
BEGIN 
    PREPARE SELECT col FROM tbl LIMIT ? OFFSET ?; 
    RETURN EXEC (lim, off); 
END;
```

I'd appreciate any help :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I see at least two issues

- `EXEC` needs the identifier that is returned by `PREPARE`, e.g.:

  ```
  sql>prepare select * from tables;
  execute prepared statement using: EXEC 2(...)
  sql>exec 2();
  ```
- The function parameters `tbl` and `col` are string values. You cannot use them as table/column identifiers.

Having said that, I am not even sure if `PREPARE` can be used inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

No, PREPARE is a top-level statement modifier.